# Exception on creating a table from C# Entity framework MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public class SalesERPDAL:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees;
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("TblEmployee");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class EmployeeBusinessLayer
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        SalesERPDAL salesDalObj = new SalesERPDAL();
        return salesDalObj.Employees.ToList(); **//Getting error on this call**
    }
}


public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

webconfig connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SalesERPDAL" connectionString="Data Source=CSCINDAI406933\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SalesERPDB;Integrated Security=True;"></add>
```

Trying to create a table "TblEmployee" from "SalesERPDAL" class, as mentioned above. But I'm getting a runtime error on calling "salesDalObj.Employees.ToList();" from GetEmployees() from EmployeeBusinessLayer class.

**Exception details: *Argument Null exception was unhandled by user code:
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Value cannot be null.***

I'm able to connect to this DataBase from a different application. I'm new to Entity framework, not sure why the application is breaking. Help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Employees should be a property, not field

Comment: public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } should do it.

Comment: @vaxlt  Thanks. But getting the below exception now, on the same method call.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Instance failure.

Comment: @CemMutlu Thanks. But getting the below exception now, on the same method call.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Instance failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass connection string name to DbContext

```
public class SalesERPDAL: DbContext
{
   public SalesERPDAL() : base("connectionStringName") { }
  public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("TblEmployee");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you should dispose  your salesDalObj after you're done. SalesERPDAL salesDalObj = new SalesERPDAL();
        return salesDalObj.Employees.ToList(); **//Getting error on this call**